# Why is a named function passed as 1st parameter to useEffect not a necessary dependency?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[Solved] I believe the 2 effects below should have the same effect.
But why does the eslint rule not complain in the second case?

It should be mandatory dependency in both case as doSomething can change and change the effect.

```
  const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    void someProp;
  }, [someProp]);


useEffect(()=> doSomething(), [doSomething]); // eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) complains if I remove the dependency
useEffect(doSomething, []); // no complaint here, why?
```

Edit:
It was actually fixed a while back (even before I wrote that question).
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18435

Comment: Perhas my question is unclear. What makes you think I do not understand the purpose of the 2nd argument?

Comment: I don't understand why you use `useCallback` to begin with. Why not use `useEffect(() => void 42, [someProp])` to begin with?

Comment: `doSomething` could be used somewhere else

Comment: That is a valid argument, but [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) returns a memorized callback. Meaning the callback function is only called when the `useCallback` dependencies change. So you could do `useEffect(doSomething)` which only executes the callback of `useCallback` if the `useCallback` dependencies change. There is no need to specify dependencies for `useEffect` in that scenario.

Comment: btw your example isn't actually using a named function, an anonymous function assigned to a variable is still an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually fixed a while back (even before I wrote that question).

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18435

The eslint-pluging-react-hook will properly warn in both case.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` should not return a value, except a clean up function.

e.g:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {}
}, [])
```

And you're using `doSomething`, which was specified outside the hook, inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question.

Comment: The reason es-lint didn't complain on the second example is because, you passed a function as the hook handler. But in the first example, you're calling a function inside `useEffect`. And anything inside the hook that is external to the hook handler needs to be specified in the dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for `useEffect` is the dependency array, in which you can describe that the effect should run if the given values are changed.
On your second case the `doSomething` function is not something the effect *uses*, but *it is the effect function itself*.

If you use it inside your effect function, eslint will notify about it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  doSomething();
}, []);
```

Comment: The effect uses that function, if the function changes we should not skip the effect. I think eslint should warn us.